# Binance API C++ - Compilation and usage

Tags: c++, binance

I'm trying to compile and use binance api library (c++) without success on Windows:https://github.com/binance-exchange/binacpp

1. Do I need to use the .o/.os files? How?
2. Is it possible to compile it in Visual Studio or only with GCC?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Right now as I see inside github repo it contains ready-made .o/.a/.so files, these files are designed for Linux and probably were created by GCC or CLang. Probably library can be compiled in Visual Studio too, but there is no Makefile or CMake-file, it means you have to create a project in Visual Studio and add all .cpp files there. Also there are dependencies like jsoncpp, etc, they are listed in [README](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binacpp/blob/master/README.md), you have to download github repositories of all dependencies and also compile theirs .cpp in Visual Studio.